# Convergence of a matrix

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $A_j$ be a sequence in $\mathbb {C}^{n\times n}$. Show that $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^\infty A_j$ converges if $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^\infty ||A_j||$ does.

Note that $\displaystyle \Vert A\Vert=\sup_{|x|=1} \vert Ax \vert$. I know that since $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^\infty ||A_j||$ does converge, then $\displaystyle \Vert A_j \Vert$ eventually converges to zero. Where do I go from here?

Comment: I'm confused by your use of $j$. Sometimes it is a subscript, sometimes it seems like a vector or scalar multiple.

Comment: @ Ed sorry about that, I fixed it.

Comment: Notice that $\| \cdot \|$ as you give defines a norm and adapt the proof that an absolutely convergent series of real numbers converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is complete, so we need only show that the sequence $S_n = \sum_{j=0}^{n} A_j$ is Cauchy.

Details:

> Suppose without loss of generality that $n>m$. Then: $\|S_n-S_m\| =\|\sum_{j=m+1}^n A_j\| \leq \sum_{j=m+1}^n \|A_j\|= |\sum_{j=0}^n \|A_j\| - \sum_{j=0}^m \|A_j\||$ Since $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \|A_j\|$ is convergent, it is Cauchy, hence it follows that $S_n$ is also Cauchy.

Comment: How'd you make the solution hidden like that?

Comment: Use >! at the start of the line (it is a bit fiddly, and I am sure there is a better way, but I am no 'La-techie'). Also, you can edit the answer to have a look (I think).

Comment: @copper you are genius.

Comment: @Klara: I am not, but your flattery is most appreciated :-).